# Star Trek kanar bottle in the Addams Family Mansion?

Tags: star-trek, props

I recently saw an episode of *The Addams Family* called "[Morticia's Dilemma](https://addamsfamily.fandom.com/wiki/Morticia%27s_Dilemma)" (S02:E14), and at around 06:20 in the episode, there was a bottle that looked like the bottles of [kanar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kanar) drunk by Cardassians in *Star Trek*.

Does anybody know the history how the props department came up with the bottle for *Star Trek*? I'm wondering if I was just seeing things, or if the props department did indeed go scrounging for weird bottle props from old television shows and found that one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Would you be able to [edit] this question to add screenshots of the respective bottles? It's not strictly necessary, but it'd be nice, as a visual aid.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133672) or [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112348) about other ST background props, or [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53296) about an old bit of sci-fi prop lore.

Comment: This isn't surprising. Lurch is probably Mr. Homn's cousin, after all.

Comment: @HamSandwich - Lurch *is* Mr Homn; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carel_Struycken

Comment: Yes, the same actors.

Answer (score 9):

The Kanar bottle seen in *Quark's Bar, Grill, Gaming House and Holosuite Arcade* is a fairly common design of spiral bottle. They were made in the 1960s (and indeed [continue to be made today](https://www.therpf.com/forums/attachments/biglots1-jpg.884548/)) by a variety of companies, mainly for the sale of [Chianti wine](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/1973-vintage-chianti-wine-bottle-33-1821607852).

[image]

That being said, although they were unable to track down the *specific* manufacturer, [the claim on QuarksBarb.com](http://www.quarksbarb.com/details/bottles.html#:%7E:text=is%20slightly%20different.-,B015,-KANAR%20%2D%20THE%20BOTTLE) is that the shorter bottle (with space for a plaque or label on the front) was more likely to have contained vinegar.

> - The spiral bottle used on the show was supposedly sold by D'Aquino
>   Italian Importing Co for their Chianti.
> - This bottle shape is also used by firms which sell flavored vinegars and is  available occasionally in gourmet stores and BigLots (and, I'm told, around Christmastime at Target).
> - The prop dept used many vinegar bottles and I believe this was a vinegar bottle, too.
> - The last one I bought was sold by Swiss American Co.
> - I contacted them and they said that they imported the bottle from Vitrocolor in Spain and had it filled locally.

Since the two shows don't share a common props department, it seems likely that their production people both went shopping at their local stores for "*weird looking bottles*" and came up with much the same answer both times, albeit decades apart.